# Docker-Compose File

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have three seperate Microservices, and for each of them in their directory I have Dockerfile.
[image: photo of my microservices]

I am beginner in Docker and I am a little confused.
for define Docker Compose file, I must define three docker-compose.yml files in the directory of each services?!
Or I must define just one docker-compose.yml file for all my services?! If yes, in which directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker compose is built for having multiple apps, with a Dockerfile it is very powerful.
To put it simply you can split a docker-compose file into things called 'services' and they act as different, separate apps/microservices, so say I wanted a nodejs app and a database within the same docker-compose file and Dockerfile:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7.7.2-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet
COPY . .
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

mongo:
  image: mongo
  name: database
  restart: always
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

web:
  build: .
  command: npm run dev
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/app/
    - /usr/app/node_modules
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
    - mongo
```

If you ran that in the directory you want to work at, it will always stay in that directory . You can name each service it's own name. This example it's mongo and web. Once running, locally you can reference and connect to your services just by using their respective names.

I recommend these two YouTube video. Quick and simple. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFl2mCHdv24&t=486s) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qw9zlE3t8Ko&t=419s)

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact I do not have problem for define Docker compose. My problem was I did not know where I must define my docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: @saharsa If you use a Dockerfile in conjunction with docker-compose then it's easy to set up virtual volumes and directories to organise. Those videos will explain so much and it's very convenient to know. If this answer answered your question remember to mark it as answered with the checkmark to help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create separate compose file. Docker compose provides you the option to specify the location of Dockerfiles in order to setup the containers. In the root folder which contains this three app create a compose file.

For an example check this file https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/docker-compose.yml

Comment: the problem is, when I try define docker-compose.yml in the root directory, it does not give me this possibility and I have just three choices, one of these services

Comment: the root directory is Eclips/Workplace/... and then these three services but I do not have any choice to select root directory and not others